# i have some question about mql4 in ordersend and orderclose in my code

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, forex

i have a small expert with mql4 for forex robot 
but i have get some problem in getting code when running this code to backtest in metatrader 4
my code details is :
i have 2 ema and when cross up get buy and when cross down get sell
but its problem to get position after crosing 2 ema in backtest.
My stoplose is fix to 10 pip but tp is 0 and we have open trade until next cross from 2 ema and then close pervios position and get new position.
i add test sterategy and show my problem in getting position

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2018"
#property link      "https://www.mql4.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

input int Ema_Fast_Period = 62;
input int Ema_Slow_Period = 30;

input int MagicNumber = 1982;
input double Lots = 0.01;
input double StopLoss = 100;
input double TakeProfit = 0;

double FastMACurrent ,SlowMACurrent ,FastMAPrevious ,SlowMAPrevious;

bool BuyCondition = False, SellCondition = False, CrossPriseWithFastMAUpShado = False, CrossPriseWithFastMADownShado = False;
//---
int Slippage=5;

double OpenPosition = 0;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|   expert OnTick function                                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
      if(Volume[0]<=1)
      {
         FastMACurrent = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Fast_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,1 );
         SlowMACurrent = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Slow_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,1 );
         FastMAPrevious = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Fast_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,2 );
         SlowMAPrevious = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Slow_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,2 ); 
      //----------------------- BUY CONDITION   
         BuyCondition = (FastMAPrevious<SlowMAPrevious && FastMACurrent>SlowMACurrent);      
      //----------------------- SELL CONDITION   
         SellCondition = (FastMAPrevious>SlowMAPrevious && FastMACurrent<SlowMACurrent);

         CrossPriseWithFastMADownShado = ( Low[1]<FastMACurrent && FastMACurrent<Open[1] );
         if( BuyCondition )
         {
            //If we have open trade before get another trade close perivios trade and save money
            if( OrderSelect(0, SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES) )
            {
               int a = OrderClose( OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),OrderClosePrice(), Slippage, clrWhite );
            }
            BuyCondition = False;
            GetBuy();
         }
         if( SellCondition )
         {
            //If we have open trade before get another trade close perivios trade and save money
            if( OrderSelect(0, SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES) )
            {
               int a = OrderClose( OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),OrderClosePrice(), Slippage, clrWhite );
            }
            SellCondition = False;
            GetSell();
         }
      }
 }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|   expert Buy Or Sell function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int GetBuy(){
   int getposition = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,Lots,Ask,Slippage,Ask-(StopLoss*Point),0,"Buy",MagicNumber,0,Blue);
   return True;
}
int GetSell(){
   int getposition = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,Lots,Bid,Slippage,Bid+(StopLoss*Point),0,"Sell",MagicNumber,0,Red);
   return True;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BehbR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code. The main problem in your code is takeprofit!
In GetBuy() and GetSell() Functions you wrote:

```
Ask+(TakeProfit*Point)
```

It returns Ask! because your TakeProfit has been set to zero. If you don't want to set Takeprofit You should write:

```
int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,Lots,Ask,Slippage,Ask-(StopLoss*Point),0,"Buy",MagicNumber,0,Blue);
```

This is the new code:

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2018"
#property link      "https://www.mql4.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

input int Ema_Fast_Period = 62;
input int Ema_Slow_Period = 30;

input int MagicNumber = 1982;
input double Lots = 0.01;
input int StopLoss = 100;
input int TakeProfit = 1000;

double FastMACurrent ,SlowMACurrent ,FastMAPrevious ,SlowMAPrevious;

bool BuyCondition = False, SellCondition = False, CrossPriseWithFastMAUpShado =     False, CrossPriseWithFastMADownShado = False;
//---
int Slippage=5;

double OpenPosition = 0;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|   expert OnTick function                                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
  if(Volume[0]<=1)
  {
     FastMACurrent = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Fast_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,1 );
     SlowMACurrent = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Slow_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,1 );
     FastMAPrevious = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Fast_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,2 );
     SlowMAPrevious = iMA(Symbol() ,PERIOD_CURRENT ,Ema_Slow_Period ,0 ,MODE_EMA ,PRICE_CLOSE ,2 ); 
  //----------------------- BUY CONDITION   
     BuyCondition = (FastMAPrevious<SlowMAPrevious && FastMACurrent>SlowMACurrent);      
  //----------------------- SELL CONDITION   
     SellCondition = (FastMAPrevious>SlowMAPrevious && FastMACurrent<SlowMACurrent);

     CrossPriseWithFastMADownShado = ( Low[1]<FastMACurrent && FastMACurrent<Open[1]         );

     if( BuyCondition )
     {
        //If we have open trade before get another trade close perivios trade and save money
        if( OrderSelect(0, SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES) )
        {
           int a = OrderClose( OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),OrderType()==OP_SELL ? Ask : Bid, Slippage, clrWhite );
        }
        if(GetBuy()) BuyCondition = False;

     }
     if( SellCondition )
     {
        //If we have open trade before get another trade close perivios trade and     save money
        if( OrderSelect(0, SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES) )
        {
           int a = OrderClose( OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),OrderType()==OP_BUY ? Bid : Ask, Slippage, clrWhite );
        }
        if(GetSell()) SellCondition = False;
     }
  }
 }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|   expert Buy Or Sell function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool GetBuy(){
   int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,Lots,Ask,Slippage,Ask-(StopLoss*Point),Ask+    (TakeProfit*Point),"Buy",MagicNumber,0,Blue);
   if(ticket > 0) return true;
   return false;
}
bool GetSell(){
   int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,Lots,Bid,Slippage,Bid+(StopLoss*Point),Bid-        (TakeProfit*Point),"Sell",MagicNumber,0,Red);
   if(ticket > 0) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
but if you run in sterategy tester in meta trader 4 you can see when open new position instantly get stoplose

Comment: Your welcome.
Yes it gets StopLoss because StopLoss has a value except Zero. But TakeProfit will be Ask or Bid Because Ask/Bid + Takeprofit(Zero)*Point = Ask/Bid + 0 = Ask/Bid

Comment: Yes i understand this error but we have another error in getting position
if you run in sterategy tester khnow it

Comment: Please run it and write the error code here. I tested and didn't get error

Comment: i have edited this issue in my Code and adding photo in my problem under the question.

Comment: Where is this photo? I can't find it